# Script Error Couldn't find module: com.test in titanium

Tags: ios, module, titanium, appcelerator

i have made my own module and while integrating with titanium project(Kitchen sink)the  **SCRIPT ERROR** appear.why??

Below is my Console error.

```
[INFO] : Found Titanium module id=facebook version=latest platform=iphone deploy-type=development path=/Users/stuxbot/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/facebook/3.1.1 
[INFO] : Deploy type: development
[INFO] : Building for target: simulator
[INFO] : Building using iOS SDK: 7.1
[INFO] : Building for iOS iPhone Simulator: 7.1
[INFO] : Building for device family: universal
[INFO] : Minimum iOS version: 6.0
[INFO] : Debugging disabled
[INFO] : Profiler disabled
[INFO] : Initiating prepare phase
[INFO] : Copying custom Info.plist from project directory
[INFO] : Forcing rebuild: custom Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier not equal to tiapp.xml <id> [INFO] : Cleaning old build directory
[INFO] : Performing full rebuild
[INFO] : Copying Xcode iOS files
[INFO] : Creating Xcode project directory: /Users/stuxbot/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Kitchen Sink/build/iphone/KitchenSink.xcodeproj
[INFO] : Writing Xcode project data file: Titanium.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
[INFO] : Writing Xcode project configuration: project.xcconfig [INFO] : Writing Xcode module configuration: module.xcconfig
[INFO] : Injecting native libraries into Xcode project file
[INFO] : Forcing rebuild: ApplicationDefaults.m has changed since last build
[INFO] : Writing application defaults: /Users/stuxbot/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Kitchen Sink/build/iphone/Classes/ApplicationDefaults.m
[INFO] : Initiating Xcode pre-compile phase
[INFO] : Processing JavaScript files
[INFO] : Loading and parsing JSS files
[INFO] : Compiling localisation files
[INFO] : Checking for Splash Screen localisation
[INFO] : Invoking xcode build
[INFO] : Finished building the application in 25s 893ms
[INFO] : Running application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] : Launching application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] : Focusing the iOS Simulator
[INFO] : Application started
[ERROR] : Script Error Couldn't find module: com.test
[ERROR] : Analytics error sending request: A connection failure occurred
[ERROR] : 2014-06-03 10:34:00.069 KitchenSink[4179:410f]
[WARN] Unable to securely connect to api.appcelerator.net with the latest TLS. Trying again with TLS1.0. It is highly suggested that the server be updated to the latest TLS support.
[ERROR] : Analytics error sending request: A connection failure occurred
```

Comment: Have you installed the module into your project?

Comment: yes in kitchen sink project..and i have followed the module development guide to create module..also the installation guide..

Comment: Create another mobile app project and include the module inside that, let me know the result

Comment: same error...couldnt find module

Comment: Can you show module tag in your tiapp.xml?

Comment: i have included module from "TIapp Editor" ..not from tiapp XML editor..

Comment: <module version="1.0" platform="iphone">com.test</module>